# NFLfastpy installed but wont import

Tags: python, pycharm

I have pip installed nflfastpy ,
But when I import it.
running only

```
import nflfastpy
```

i get this error message

```
(pythonCoursera) C:\Users\austi\PycharmProjects\pythonCoursera>python sportsbet.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\austi\PycharmProjects\pythonCoursera\sportsbet.py", line 2, in <module>
    import nflfastpy as nfl
  File "C:\Users\austi\anaconda3\envs\pythonCoursera\lib\site-packages\nflfastpy\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    default_headshot = mpl_image.imread(headshot_url)
  File "C:\Users\austi\anaconda3\envs\pythonCoursera\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 1536, in imread
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Please open the URL for reading and pass the result to Pillow, e.g. with ``np.array(PIL.Image.open(urllib.request.urlopen(url)))``.
```

on 1 single line of code, nothing else in the file,
I've trie a few versions of it, cant seem to figure it out.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

That library has a bug and seems to be not actively maintained. You are on your own. At least that image loading error can be avoided by removing the dead code in `nflfastpy/__init__.py` like the following.

```
...
#default_headshot = mpl_image.imread(headshot_url)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is late now but I was able to fix this importing these libraries:

`import PIL import urllib.request`

then adding the following lines:

`urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fantasydatapros /nflfastpy/master/nflfastpy/images/headshot.png", "headshot.png")`

`default_headshot = PIL.Image.open("headshot.png")`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).